# Optimus on W520 with external DP monitor: LVDS is disconnected so no laptop panel

Tags: xorg, nvidia-optimus

I have a ThinkPad W520 with ubuntu 16.04 and the Nvidia drivers, installed from Ubuntu repositories (or the PPA, the problem I have is the same with both the 367.57 and 375.20 drivers). It's a Quadro 1000M display. 
It works fine with BIOS is set to discrete.
When in discrete mode, a script deletes xorg.conf (well, moves it) and the config works great.

When I set the BIOS to Optimus, and prime-select nvidia I can't access the laptop panel. During startup, a script writes an xorg.conf.

xrandr gives this output

```
 Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 2280, maximum 16384 x 16384         
   VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   LVDS-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+1200 (normal left inverted right x axi#
      1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00••
   DP-0 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518#
```

and nothing I can do will reconnect with LVDS-0.

The laptop panel shows some leftover text from the boot phase (a report on the drive being clean). 
Entering a virtual console blanks the DP1 screen, and the console is in the laptop panel. Resuming the X sessions reawakens the DP1 screen while the laptop reverts to the boot text screen.

I have set grub to text only, it made no difference. 
I guess something is wrong with the xorg.conf I get.

```
  Section "ServerLayout"
       Identifier "layout"
       Screen 0 "nvidia"
       Inactive "intel"
   EndSection

   Section "Device"
       Identifier "intel"
       Driver "modesetting"
      BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
      Option "AccelMethod" "None"
  EndSection

  Section "Screen"
      Identifier "intel"
      Device "intel"
  EndSection

  Section "Device"
      Identifier "nvidia"                                                     
      Driver "nvidia"
      BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
      Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
  EndSection

  Section "Screen"
      Identifier "nvidia"
      Device "nvidia"
      Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
      Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
  EndSection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strangely for such old hardware, upgrading to kernel 4.8 makes quite a difference. This is with either 16.10 or the 4.8 kernel available in 16.04 (currently in proposed).

To boot with Optimus or the dedicated Nvidia hardware, all that is needed is one kernel boot parameter: <s>nox2pic</s> `nox2apic`
I am using 16.04.1 but with the 4.8 kernel from 16.04.2

It is not necessary to specify anything else. Neither is it necessary to manually provide brightness settings for the xorg.conf file. In fact, the old tweaks I found to add brightness handling to xorg.conf were causing the Intel card to disappear as a provider, which I discovered by adding back the contents of /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d in chunks to bisect the trouble.

So after that, booting with optimus, in Nvidia and with two external monitors now connects the two DP monitors and the internal screen (in other words, the Intel card and the Nvidia card now both show via `xrandr --listproviders` which is the critical result). However, while the cursor appears on the laptop screen, the background is black and no windows can be dragged there. So this is partial success

Update: This last problem (black background, no windows draggable) was Unity. Installing XFCE and using an XFCE session works: all three monitors are good. I still use lightdm. Gnome works too although I don't use it.

So this is good enough for me.  have all three monitors arranged left to right horizontally.